# How can I manually return or throw a validation error/exception in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, exception, error-handling

Have a method that's importing CSV-data into a Database. I do some basic validation using

```
class CsvImportController extends Controller
{
    public function import(Request $request)
    {   
        $this->validate($request, [
            'csv_file' => 'required|mimes:csv,txt',
        ]);
```

But after that things can go wrong for more complex reasons, further down the rabbit hole, that throws exceptions of some sort. I can't write proper validation stuff to use with the `validate` method here, but, I really like how Laravel works when the validation fails and how easy it is to embed the error(s) into the blade view etc, so...

Is there a (preferably clean) way to *manually* tell Laravel that "I know I didn't use your `validate` method right now, but I'd really like you to expose this error here as if I did"? Is there something I can return, an exception I can wrap things with, or something?

```
try
{
    // Call the rabbit hole of an import method
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    // Can I return/throw something that to Laravel looks 
    // like a validation error and acts accordingly here?
}
```

Comment: What about extending the validation of laravel to add your complex treatment like yhis `Validator::extend('foo', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return $value == 'foo';
        });` then you can add the foo rule in the rules `'csv_file' => 'required|foo|mimes:csv,txt',` ??

Comment: @Svish Do you have your custom validation class to throw on validation error ?

Comment: It's a legacy project (and I'm a Laravel newb), so I don't really know what I should add in a potential validator class/function. So, I'd prefer to just catch "whatever goes wrong down that rabbit hole" and pretend it was validated and failed, rather than trying to find out everything that *actually* might get checked down there and pull it into a validation type step. 

My task is basically just to make errors prettier right now, as one currently just gets a javascript alert with "oops, something went wrong".

Comment: @Svish I think **madalinivascu's** solution is your answer.

Comment: you can catch the error message in catch block and do your stuff. like this
`try
  {
   //my stuff 
  }
  catch (Exception $ex)
  {
   echo $ex->getMessage(); //Message
   //$ex->getFile(); //File
   //$ex->getLine(); //Line
  }`

Comment: or you can also do you custom validation and throw the error and then handle it in catch like this
`try
{
 $validator = Validator::make($request, ['csv_file' => 'required|mimes:csv,txt']);
 if ($validator->fails())
 {
  throw new Exception(implode('<br>', $validator->errors()->all()), 999);
 }
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
 if ($ex->getCode() == 999)
 {
  //this is a custom error
 }
 echo $ex->getMessage(); //Message
}`

Comment: @ako Yep! Marked it now :)

Answer (score 319, accepted):

As of laravel 5.5, the [`ValidationException` class has a static method `withMessages`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/77227bd9f53ac0b6ad07e9007582443e8767f612/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php#L69) that you can use:

```
$error = \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::withMessages([
   'field_name_1' => ['Validation Message #1'],
   'field_name_2' => ['Validation Message #2'],
]);
throw $error;
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

**Update**

The message does not have to be wrapped in an array. You can also do:

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

throw ValidationException::withMessages(['field_name' => 'This value is incorrect']);
```

Comment: Ah! That *did* work, and also removed the "need" for a helper method to remove the ugly messagebag stuff.  Thanks!

Comment: it is almos like that, instead of being a simple array, its a multidimentional array, this one works 
```$error = ValidationException::withMessages([
           "one_thing" => ["Validation Message #1"],
            "another_thing" => ['Validation Message #2']
        ]); ```

Comment: @JosePalazuelos Since Laravel > v5.5 is casting the message argument into an array with Arr::wrap($value) it's not necessary to pass the 2D array, it will work with a simple key-values array. See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php#L73

Comment: Works like a charm on 6.6. The only downside is how it inhibits other validation error messages.

Comment: This is great way for extra checks not related to one field, for example for checking if user is trying to send message for product that belongs to him, this way you can put simple `if ($this->user() === $this->product->user_id)` inside of 
`protected function prepareForValidation()` and just throw `ValidationException` with custom message before other checks happen! (of course all this inside of `FormRequest`)

Comment: why do i get Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Validator' not found", exception: "Error" ??? i'm in laravel 8

Comment: @FernandoTorres You must be using the Validator facade somewhere in the controller, and need to import the namespace.

Comment: @IGP If you have an instance of the validator object performing the validation, and you want to propagate any other exception messages that may be contained in it to the new ValidationException you're manually throwing, you can always merge: `throw ValidationException::withMessages(array_merge($validator->getMessageBag()->getMessages(), ['other_key' => 'Other error message']))`

Comment: Mārtiņš Briedis' answer below accomplishes the same task, but perhaps in a cleaner fashion.

Answer (score 41):

Simply return from controller:

```
return back()->withErrors('your error message');
```

---

or:

```
throw ValidationException::withMessages(['your error message']);
```

Comment: This method works but because I have gone back(), the form won't display previous values using {{ old('fieldname') }}

Comment: add withInput(), like that return back()->withErrors('error')->withInput();

Comment: Best answer (don't forget about `withInput()`

Comment: Applicable fix for Laravel 8 in 2021. Can also pass array `->withErrors(['field' => 'Error message'])`

Answer (score 39):

**Laravel <= 9.*** this solution worked for me:

```
// Empty data and rules
$validator = \Validator::make([], []);

// Add fields and errors
$validator->errors()->add('fieldName', 'This is the error message');

throw new \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException($validator);
```

Comment: This is the official way that the Laravel core codebase uses as well.

Answer (score 17):

##### In Laravel 8 and above, the following works in both a controller and a model:

```
return back()->withErrors(["email" => "Are you sure the email is correct?"])->withInput();
```

This will return the user to the view they were on previously, displaying the specified error for the specified field (if it exists), and re-populate all the fields with the information the user just entered, allowing them to simply adjust the incorrect field rather than fill out the whole form again.

Another functionally similar alternative would be to do something like this:

```
throw ValidationException::withMessages(['email' => 'Are you sure the email is correct?']);
```

Comment: Why there is a return statement after the exception?

Comment: @AtanasBeychev Good catch, fixed.

Comment: Both these options were already provided as [an answer in 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48619721/1255289).

Comment: @miken32 Not only is that a code-only answer with no explanation, it also lacks the crucial `withInput()` method and showing how to pass arrays through, both of which my answer contains.

Answer (score 15):

For Laravel 5.8:

.

The easiest way to throw an exception is like this:

```
throw new \ErrorException('Error found');
```

Comment: please explain how is this going to handle the validation errors ?

Comment: This is rather vague. Laravel offers better ways to indicate the type of error.

Comment: This will throw the ```ErrorException``` exception. And will not be converted into Validation Message. Insated it will throw the error code of 500

Answer (score 5):

you can try a custom message bag

```
try
{
    // Call the rabbit hole of an import method
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    return redirect()->to('dashboard')->withErrors(new \Illuminate\Support\MessageBag(['catch_exception'=>$e->getMessage()]));
}
```

Comment: That *almost* worked. The `MessageBag` doesn't seem to like exceptions? So calling it with `new MessageBag(['exception' => $e])` results in an empty error-set, while `new MessageBag(['exception' => $e->getMessage()])` does not... 

Comment: you need to convert $e to text, or use a custom message

Comment: _Never_ show generic Exception class messages to the client! They may leak sensitive information, like database credentuals, sql queryies, even URLs with API keys. This is a _bad_ idea. Only return exception messages if you control/know what kind of exception it is.

Answer (score 2):

As of on **Laravel 5.5 >** you can use

`throw_if` -  throws the given exception if a given boolean expression evaluates to `true`

```
$foo = true;
throw_if($foo, \Exception::class, 'The foo is true!');
```

or

`throw_unless` -  throws the given exception if a given boolean expression evaluates to `false`

```
$foo = false;
throw_unless($foo);
```

[See here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-throw-if)

Answer (score -1):

Although my answer might be a little different than what you are asking but it might help others who land up on this page when trying to validating customly. If you want to validate with custom validations then you can something like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    "zips" => [
        "required",
        "array",
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
            if (count($value) > 1 && !$request->user()->hasActiveSubscription()) {
                $fail('You must have an active subscription to add multiple zips.');
            }
        }
    ],
]);
```