# Manually throwing validation exception in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have been referencing this stackoverflow answer

[How can I manually return or throw a validation error/exception in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219542/how-can-i-manually-return-or-throw-a-validation-error-exception-in-laravel)

to throw validation exception in laravel. I am using form request first to check input type from the form and need to validate file from that input. I have to read the excel file and validate each data from that excel file. So I am using ValidationException inorder track those errors.

Here is my line of code

```
private function invokeValidationException($field, $message)
{
    Log::info($message);
    $validator = Validator::make([],[]); // Empty data and rules fields
    $validator->errors()->add($field, $message);
    throw new ValidationException($validator);
}
```

same problem using `ValidationException::withMessages`

So When it is invoked I am not getting application exception.

```
//Calling exception case
$this -> invokeValidationException('WORK_PLEASE' ,'Something went wrong. Please try again!');

Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException: The given data was invalid.
```

I am throwing `something went wrong` but getting `The given data is invalid` which is related to ValidationException

Comment: I don't quite understand what your desired behaviour is. The exception is thrown right? What exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: I am throwing 'something went wrong ' but getting 'The given data is invalid' which is related to ValidationException

Comment: I just looked at the source of ValidationException. It seems that you can't override the exception text. Depending on where you want your output you can also pass a response object to the ValidationException, which presumably gets send if the Exception is thrown. See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php#L56 for reference

Comment: @JensV So is there any way?

Comment: Where do you want your text to be displayed?

Comment: I want to show red error at upload file input which is working if file mime type and size validation. I need this to work with given file input name as key and message as error