# Laravel validation fails, but $errors is always empty

Tags: laravel

Im migrating a cms from 5.7 to latest, and i havent been working with laravel for 3 years.

i have an error: in a nutshell: i have  a form, i have a controller with save action, validation rules & messages and validation. Now the validator seems to be working (fails), and redirects me to the prev. rout, BUT the $errors var is always empy and the old form values are not stored.

Posting a valid form works ok.

i paste the relevalt stuff below:

ROUTS

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['adm', 'sentinelauth', 'web' ]], function () {



        Route::group(['prefix' => 'roles'], function () {
            Route::get('/', 'BE\RolesController@getIndex' )               ->name('adm_roles_index');
            Route::get('/add', 'BE\RolesController@addAction' )           ->name('adm_roles_add');
            Route::get('/{role}', 'BE\RolesController@editAction')        ->name('adm_roles_edit');
            Route::post('/save', 'BE\RolesController@submitAction')       ->name('adm_roles_save');
        });

/// some more routs ehere
}
```

Controller (relevant stuff)

```
 public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this -> addPageAction($request);
    }

    public function editAction(Role $role, Request $request)
    {
        return $this -> addPageAction($request, $role);
    }

    private function addPageAction(Request $request, $role = null)
    {

        $mode            = 'edit';
        $_userRoles = array();
        $activationStatus = false;
        $roles = false;

        if (!$role)
        {
            $mode = 'add';
        }
        else
        {
            if ($role->id == 1) { // editing the supervisor is not allowed, redirect to list page
                return redirect( route('adm_roles_index') );
            }
        }

        return view('BE.roles.edit') -> with([
            'action'          => $mode,
            'data'       => $role,
        ]);
    }

    public function submitAction(Request $request)
    {
        $messages = [
            'name.required' => 'The name is required.',
            'name.unique' => 'The name is already in use.',
            'slug.required' => 'The slug is required.',
            'slug.unique' => 'The slug is already in use.',
        ];

        $validatorRules = array(
            'name' => 'required|unique:roles',
            'slug' => 'required|unique:roles',
        );

        if ( !empty($request->id) ) {
            $role = Sentinel::findRoleById($request->id);

            if ($role) {
                $validatorRules['name'] = 'required|unique:roles,name,' . $role->id;
                $validatorRules['slug'] = 'required|unique:roles,slug,' . $role->id;
            }

        }

        $this -> validate($request, $validatorRules, $messages);

       /// some more stuff down here for storing the roles etc. but not so important
}
```

Blade

```
    {{ dump($errors) }}

            {!! Form::open(array('url' => route('adm_roles_save'), 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'Form', 'name' => 'Form', )) !!}


          {!! Form::label('name', 'Name', []) !!}
          {!! Form::text('name', old('name', (!empty($data -> name)) ? $data -> name : null ),
                                                    [ 'placeholder' => 'Name',
                                                      'class' => ($errors->has('name') ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control' )
                                                    ]
                                                ) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This blade always shows

```
Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag {#776 ▼
  #bags: []
}
```

Comment: Check like this on your blade `@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif`

Comment: no success....
posting an empty form shows me nothing => validation IS running, because im redirected, but the errors are not passed.... i guess

Comment: The function is `submitAction`?

Comment: processing the POST? yes. if i dd() the request before validation, the values are there (empty or npot, depending on the form of course). if i submit an invalid form the validation runs and the redirection happens, because making a dd('xxx'); after validation will not be executed. if a valid form is posted, the validation passes and the func. continues.

Comment: Actually  the problem is, you make the validation. But not return anything. Where it will return?

Comment: well, according to Laravel docs:

"As you can see, we pass the desired validation rules into the validate method. Again, if the validation fails, the proper response will automatically be generated. If the validation passes, our controller will continue executing normally." 

and it redirects... from the failed validation, so the return is handled by the validation. (BTW in 5.2 worked/works with no problem. but i dont see any difference...)

Comment: There are some changes after 5.5, 
I just saw it here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47223679/4575350

Comment: well there is SOME progress, but essentially the result is the same. Like 
`        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $validatorRules, $messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect(route('adm_roles_add'))
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }`

works, and if i dump the $validator in the IF, the validator object exists and it is correct. But it seams that the redirection does not recives anything (sample code taken from laravel 7.x docs).

Comment: Did you check it with `required` or `unique` validation?

Comment: required fails. i dont get to unique since i dont have records... but required fails (if i post an empty form of course)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219081/discussion-between-imodi-and-sta).

Comment: do you have the `ShareErrorsFromSession` middleware in place?

Comment: ahhhhh...no..... didnt have it in 5.3.... i have a fresh install of 7.iDontKnowWhat but no Share... middleware.... where can i get it? but thanks i belive we are on the right track here...

where should i find it?

Comment: BTW the route group includes the web mw.:  Route::group(['middleware' => ['adm', 'sentinelauth', 'web' ]], function () { ... }

Comment: found it, in kernel.php, it IS included in web group... si yes, its added.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest checking the result of your validation from inside your controller. you can use `Validator::make()` to prevent the automatic redirect that `->validate()` causes when validation fails.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $validatorRules);
if ($validator->fails()) dd($validator->errors());
```

Comment: thanks, but already did it. in the controller the validation is fine. it seams that the error and old inpit is not passed between views, although the middleware is there...

Answer (score 3):

go to Http/Kernel.php

move this line: \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class

from $middlewareGroups array to $middleware array.

DONE!

Comment: Pefect solution, Can you explain why it was happening?